# Does light (photons) exert reaction force on it's source?

Tags: forces, visible-light, photons, laser, rocket-science

I know that photons/ light when incident on a surface exerts forces on it (aka radiation pressure) and it is also used for applications such as solar sails or laser propulsion. This phenomenon is similar to wind sails, where wind exerts pressure on the sails.

In rocket chemical propulsion, high-velocity exhaust gas produces a reaction force to propel the rocket. Does the light/photon also produce a reaction force on its source? For example, does a torch or a laser device experiences force in the opposite direction of the light? Can it be used similar to the rocket propulsion?

Similar question:
[Action - Reaction pair, through photons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10666/action-reaction-pair-through-photons)

Comment: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-018-03165-4

Comment: short answer yes.

Comment: As I mentioned here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/677397/123208 it takes a *lot* of light to produce significant pressure.

Comment: FWIW, in this answer I give the equations for an ideal photon engine: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/345492/123208

Comment: [How can a red light photon be different from a blue light photon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/540485/37364)

Answer (score 1):

Radiation pressure indicates that photons carry momentum.  Conservation of momentum requires a reaction force on the source.